Chrome Extension that adds an element left of all google search results
I am creating a chrome extension that inserts an element in front of every google search result. I am doing this by looping over all div's with an id of "a h3" on the google search page.
However I am having a problem with getting my injected element to show up on the left side of the results, i can only seem to be able to get it to work overlapping the result. Is there a way to get it so it injects the square in front of the result?
the script that injects the square can be found below:
import React, { useEffect, useRef, useState } from "react"
function ContentScript() {
  const indexRef = useRef(1)
  useEffect(() => {
    const addShadowDivs = () => {
      const searchResultDivs = document.querySelectorAll("a h3")

      searchResultDivs.forEach((div) => {
        if (div.parentElement.querySelector('[data-extension-shadow="true"]')) {
          console.log("Shadow host already exists for this div")
          return
        }

        const shadowHost = document.createElement("div")
        shadowHost.setAttribute("data-extension-shadow", "true")
        shadowHost.style.position = "relative"

        const shadowRoot = shadowHost.attachShadow({ mode: "open" })
        const shadowContent = document.createElement("div")
        shadowContent.id = indexRef.current.toString()
        shadowContent.className = "content-shadow-dom"
        shadowContent.style.float = "left"
        shadowContent.style.width = "40px"
        shadowContent.style.height = "100px"
        shadowContent.style.position = "absolute"
        shadowContent.style.left = "-10px"
        shadowContent.style.zIndex = "100000"
        shadowContent.style.textAlign = "center"
        shadowContent.style.backgroundColor = "#f0f0f0"

        indexRef.current += 1
        shadowRoot.appendChild(shadowContent)
        console.log(div.parentElement)
        div.parentNode.insertBefore(shadowHost, div)
      })
    }

    addShadowDivs()

    const observer = new MutationObserver((mutations) => {
      mutations.forEach((mutation) => {
        if (mutation.type === "childList") {
          addShadowDivs()
        }
      })
    })

    observer.observe(document.body, { childList: true, subtree: true })

    return () => observer.disconnect()
  }, [])

  return null
}

export default ContentScript


Tried multiple things like adding the shadowContent to different parts of the original DOM and changing all possible values on the shadowContent

What does the DOM look like when you look at it in dev tools?

Change your "-10px" to -50px.
